# Error when using fbox numbering with tasks package

Tags: tasks, fbox

When I insert "**\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries \fbox{\arabic*}}**" in the preamble, I receive an error ***"! Argument of \boxframe has an extra }.\par \item***" but it's good If I don't insert that. My codes are :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath,amsfonts,tasks,enumitem}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries \fbox{\arabic*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{EXERCISES}\\
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Prove the following by induction on $n$, where $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.
        \begin{tasks}(2)
          \task $\sum_{r=0}^n 2^r=2^{n+1}-1$
          \task $5+5^2+\cdots+5^n=\frac{5(5^n-1)}{4}$
          \task $\sum_{r=0}^n a^r=\frac{a(a^n-1)}{a-1};~a\in\mathbb R$\\
          \task The sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$.
          \task* $(1+a)+2(2+a)+3(3+a)+\cdots+n(n+a)=\frac{n}{6}(n+1)(3a+2n+1);~a\in\mathbb R$
          \task* $5(4)+6(5)+7(6)+\cdots+n(n-1)=\frac{1}{3}(n^3-n-60);~\forall n\geq 5$
          \task* $1^4+2^4+3^4+\cdots+n^4=\frac{n}{30}(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$
        \end{tasks}
  \item Prove the following statements by induction.
        \begin{tasks}[counter-format={\bfseries tsk[1].}](2)
          \task $\sum_{r=1}^n r^5=\frac{n^2}{12}(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)$
          \task $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{r}{r+1}$
          \task $\prod_{r=1}^n r^{12}=(r!)^{12}$

        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thanks advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\fbox` is a fragile command, it needs to be protected in this case:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries\protect\fbox{\arabic*}}
```

Comment: +1 but `\fbox` from LaTeX is not fragile: it is package `xcolor` (loaded by `tasks`)  which makes it fragile. Furthermore, this "fragile" matters in such `\labelenumi` due to `enumitem` package. Without enumitem if one does `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries \fbox{\arabic{enumi}}}` for example, there is no problem, even though `\fbox` is "fragile" due to xcolor.

Comment: and only to be complete, `\protect` normally would do nothing in `\labelenumi`. But package `enumitem` does give `\protect` its protection activity, precisely because package `enumitem` hacks the way labels of items are done. I hope I am not too pedantic, but this is to clarify, because in LaTeX `\protect` acquires its specific meaning only in certain contexts like in `\section` arguments. The fact that it works here is related to `enumitem`. The fact that it is needed is caused by `xcolor`.

Comment: I also want to use this command in \labelenumii e.g.: *\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\itshape \alph*)}* in the preamble but it doesn't work. Can you help me ?